# Run shell script that runs python commands in crontab

Tags: python, shell, cron

I am trying to run a shell script from my crontab that contains the following:

```
python -u - << EOF >> /path/to/log/file
from module import script
script.run()
EOF
```

When I run the above code manually in the console, everything works just as expected.  However, when crontab runs it, no output is being created.

I cannot check `/var/log/cron` since I don't have `root` access and I cannot login as root. 
I saw people discussing this and accepted answers were suggesting adding 
`#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of the python script. In my case, `script.py` is the main script, but that calls a large number of other python scripts.

Also, the shell script that calls the python script is executable and it has the correct permissions.

Comment: Try using full path to python in the first line?(ie. `/usr/bin/python -u...`)

Comment: This is probably an environment inheritance issue.  Cron doesn't run your full environment (specifically, it doesn't inherit your path or other items from `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, and friends).  If you worry about the cron job not being run at all, consider putting `date` before the python call.  Also consider redirecting stderr to your log file: add a space and then `2>&1` after the path at the end of your piped python call.